# Prismic.io with Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, prismic.io

I'm trying to integrate prismic.io into an existing project in which I'm using handlebars as a templating engine.

Here is an example how to render a view with Pug from Prismic.io documentation:

```
div.welcome
    img(src=pagecontent.getImage('page.image').url, class='star')
    != pagecontent.getStructuredText('page.title').asHtml(ctx.linkResolver)
    != pagecontent.getStructuredText('page.description').asHtml(ctx.linkResolver)
```

Works fine, but when I'm trying to do something like this in Handlebars:

```
{{{pagecontent.getStructuredText('page.title').asHtml(ctx.linkResolver)}}}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error: Parse error on line 13: ...
>   {{{pagecontent.getStructuredText('p
>   -----------------------^ Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Is there a way I can use prismic.io with Handlebars templating engine?

Answer (score 0):

You need register the functions as Handlebars helpers otherwise you can not call them. For example:

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({
 defaultLayout: 'main',
 extname: '.hbs',
 layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname,'/views/layouts'),
 helpers: {

    PrismicText: (data) => {
        return PrismicDOM.RichText.asText(data, PrismicConfig.linkResolver)
    }
}
}));
```